# merge and dedup two tables in sql

Tags: sql

I need to merge two tables. The idea is table b's score is use as default, only the rows from table a with same group, pid, but different scores are added into table b.

Table a

```
 group    pid   score   country 
 --------------------------------------
 T1 aa  10.1    US     
 T1 aa  10.1    FR  
 T1 aa  10.1    UK  
 T1 aa  10.1    CS  
 T1 aa  16.2    BR
```

Table b

```
 group    pid   score   country 
 --------------------------------------
 T1 aa  10.1    Default
```

Desired result:

```
 group    pid   score   country 
 --------------------------------------
 T1 aa  10.1    Default     
 T1 aa  16.2    BR
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select b.*
from b
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.group = a.group and
                        b.pid = a.pid
                        b.score = a.score
                 );
```